# Make derived class able to run parent private method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, events, inheritance

It should be a stupid question, but I'm stuck for long :(
I have a class with a generic method that performs some entities initialization.

```
public class Base
{
    private Base()
    {
        // do things
        // fire OnCreated event
    }
    private void InitializeEntity<T>()
    {
        // initialize entities of class T
    }
}
```

This method `InitializeEntity` must be executed for specified entities just after the class gets created. I dont want to make the method public to prevent its execution at inproper point, but i need any derived classes to be able to execute this method at OnCreated event. My problem is that i have no idea how to expose this private method to derived classes :( It should be something like in EF done:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Probably there should be an alternative way to achive this. I appreciate any help.
**UPDATE**
Guys, **"This method `InitializeEntity` must be executed for specified entities just after the class gets created. I dont want to make the method public (should say or protected) to prevent its execution at inproper point"**. I want derived classes not be able to run it at any other time but base class `OnCreated` event. I want them to have access to this method only within the `OnCreated` event or something like that to cause entities initialization only at this point.

Comment: Why not make it `protected`?

Comment: Not possible. You cannot limit visibility to within specific methods.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead am I able to pass a kind of delegate or any other proxy for this?

Answer (score 3):

Make it [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bcd5672a.aspx) instead:

```
public class Base
{
    protected void InitializeEntity<T>()
    {
        // initialize entity class T
    }
}
```

If you'd like to ensure that it can only be called from a class within the same assembly, you might want to consider making it [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c5ka91b.aspx) (or perhaps `protected internal`):

```
public class Base
{
    internal void InitializeEntity<T>()
    {
        // initialize entity class T
    }
}
```

Note this will allow the method to be called from any class within the same assembly (or any assembly referenced by an `InternalVisibleToAttribute` in that assembly), so it's up to you to ensure that you use it appropriately.

Comment: @jim It's still a little hard to understand what you're looking for. Could you provide some example code of when and how you would like it to be executed and in what cases you want to prohibit it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to call `InitializeEntity<T>` directly, but just want to make it called, pass some kind of flag to the base constructor. To workaround `T` issue, Reflection can be used.

```
public class Base
{
    protected Base(Type type = null)
    {
        // 1. Base constructor code
        if (type != null)
        {
            // this will to InitializeEntity<type>();
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Base).GetMethod("InitializeEntity", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            generic.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }
    private void InitializeEntity<T>()
    {
        // 2. Initialize entities of class T
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(typeof(Entity))
    {
        // 3. Derived constructor code
    }
}
```

But there is of course a limitation that derived constructor code will be executed after initializing entities.